# Is there a way to change caption for first row of a table without id or name?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is some sample code:

```
<table>

 <tr>
  <td>Caption1</td>
  <td>Caption2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input id="input1" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="input2" type="text"></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Given the above code, with only id of input field in second row, how can I change the caption from "Caption2" to something else? 
And how can I hide the whole second column?

PS: only pure js or Jquery is allowed to use.

Comment: How do you select the table from other tables in the same HTML page?

Comment: is the a class/id for any of the container elements....

Comment: @JaredPar the input id is unique, so I guess we could get the table with input id.

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry I can hardly really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse the DOM

```
$("#input1")       /* start with the ID you want */
 .closest("table") /* traverse up to find the table tag */
 .find("tr")       /* find tr tags */
 .first()          /* just grab the first (header) row */
 .find("td")       /* grab all td tags */
 .last()           /* we want the last one here */
 .html("new caption"); /* update the HTML */
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LMLdR/

All mushed together:

```
$("#input1").closest("table").find("tr").first().find("td").last().html("new caption");
```

Comment: This one seems legit, I will give a try.

Comment: As to hide the whole second column, I guess below code could work?
$("#input1")
 .closest("table") /* traverse up to find the table tag */
 .find("tr")       /* find tr tags */
 .first()          /* just grab the first one */
 .find("td").hide();

Comment: that should work... play with the fiddle above to test for sure

Comment: Thanks for your help, together with this one, I think the problem is solved. http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/FyMRy/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) like,

```
$(function(){
   $('td:contains(Caption2)').text('New Caption');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8PB3D/)

**Alternatively,** you can use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like,

```
$(function(){
    $('tr:first td:eq(1)').text('New Caption');
});
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/8PB3D/1/)

You can use the way from `#input1` also like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#input1').closest('tr')// finds the row having #input1
                .prev('tr') // finding the previous row
                .find('td:eq(1)') // get the second column
                .text('New Caption'); // set the new caption
});
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8PB3D/2/)

Comment: Is there a better way to not to mention "Caption2" in the jquery? since Caption2 is dynamically generated from DB and there's chance other td happens to have the same text "Caption2". But the input id is unique on this specific page.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to `select the first row` and then `the second column` like this

```
$( "table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)" ).html("new Caption");
```

Comment: if there are two tables, I guess the code would change both content of both tables. So probably not work as I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the first tr and then its first td

```
$('table tr:first td:first').text("you new caption");
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first task (changing the caption from "Caption2" to something else) you can use something like:

```
   $(function(){
       $('#input2').click(function(){
          //get child index WRT parent tr
          var parent = $(this).parent()
          var index_row = $(parent).index(); 
          //assuming the structure of the html is not going to change
          $(parent).parent().prev().children().eq(index_row).html('Something Else');
       });
   });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8Jvjv/

Comment: If you want to change the caption related to a specific input (for example the caption1 related to #input1, with my code you can add a class to each input (for example class="input") and in my code you only need to change the $('#input2') to $('.input') and is going to work.